# Объединить метки [bitrix24] и [битрикс24]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть две метки:

- [bitrix24](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitrix24) - 78 вопросов
- [битрикс24](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%8124) - 87 вопросов

Надо-бы их объединить (они не синонимизированы - я проверял).